# Maximum power transfer and minimization of signal reflection: When should what be applied

Tags: rf, transmission-line, impedance-matching, reflection

Impedance matching is the practice of designing the input impedance of an electrical load or the output impedance of its corresponding signal source to maximize the power transfer or minimize signal reflection from the load. In case of maximizing the power transfer the optimal condition we want to archieve is:

$$ Z_S=Z^*_L $$

and in case when we want to minimize
signal reflection the desired condition is

$$ Z_S=Z_L $$

The Question is can we say in in denpendence of given situation how the decide when one wants to maximize the power transfer and when to minimize signal reflection. Are there any creteria know how to decide?

Of course, if we have only a source, *no transmission lines*, and we want maximize the power transfer, then doubtless maximizing the power transfer is the right choice.

But what what about the case when we have a source, a load and transmission line between them:

[image]

Or even a more complicated case we have again source and load, but now two different transmission lines (ie having different impedances, being build of different materials) between them:

[image]

Or even more complicated situations which I not want to draw, and so on.

Based on which creteria we can decide with option is more important here?

The maximization of the power transfer (for \$Z_S\$ and \$Z_L\$ and ignore the \$Z_0, Z_1\$ of the transmission lines) or minimization of signal reflection (for \$Z_S, Z_0\$ and then for \$Z_S, Z_1\$ and then the same story with \$Z_L\$ instead of \$Z_S\$)? Since the two mathematical conditions on impedances are different we cannot garantee that in general both conditions are satisfied simultaneously (for example when we deal with non trivial reactant components).

How to decide which practice of the two we should do in such case?

Note also that this question is closely related to my [Maximum power transfer and minimization of wave reflection: Understanding the difference on intuitive level](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/594939/maximum-power-transfer-and-minimization-of-wave-reflection-understanding-the-di), but there the focus was on intuitional way to distinguish between maximization the power transfer and minimization of signal reflection, while here I'm interested on understanding when should be applied/prefered what? And how is it possible to decide it?

**ADDITIONAL IMPORTANT POINT**: ZelmaB noticed in his answer correctly that in my question isn't adressed to a concrete rf system/application. Yes,
that's true and this is done intensionally because the main motivation in this
question to find out preferably abstract criteria when for a system
abstractly given as source, load and transmission line between them
our task is to choose a maximization of power transfer and when the
minimization of reflexion of signal waves.

If you like thinking in examples, I think ZelmaB gave below two very representative examples which also sprout the the heart of my understand problem in good way as I think, I tried to explain it below:

1. transmitter circuit (as sourse) and output antenna (as load).
   Between them we assume that the is a transmission line
2. high speed signals running through a transmission line between two ICs,
   one considered as source, one as load

What follows now is essentially rephrasing my comments below on ZelmaB's answer.

He wrote that for **Ex 1)** we have to perform maximum power transfer and for
**Ex 2)** the minimization of reflected signal. Clearly, this
sounds reasonable from viewpoint of our everyday experience.
But what is the precise scientific/formal reason that we chose in these two
examples as the matching technique we choose and not respectively the other one.

Let's focuss on Ex 1): Why we not perform on the minimization of signal waves reflexions caused by transmission line between the transmitter circuit and the output antenna, instead of maximizing the power transfer?

Is there a formal reason (not "everyday experience" reason!) why we take here
this choice and not the other one? Eg can we argue like that is
this case the reflexion effects due to transmission lines are here
negligible, because  ... (maybe these are to short with respect to
wave length of the signal; I don't know, that's just an idea, I'm not
sure if that's the correct reason).

But I hope that my last comments help the reader of this question
to point out the problem I have and understand for what kind of arguments I'm looking for. As a mathematician I have namely
some problems with "everyday experience" arguments, and prefer to see some
formal criteria (eg something like "that's the case when the length
of transmission line behaves so and so with respect the signal wave length, and so on)

Comment: You need to \ $ here for math.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question depends on what your are trying to achieve.

What is you application?

For example, when doing wireless communication, usually you would want to maximize power output out of your antenna which implies matching to maximum power transfer between your transmitter and antenna.
On other case, like high speed signals between ICs, you might not care so much about power but would like to maintain your signal's integrity by matching to minimize reflections between ICs.

Comment: When I posted this question, I hadn't a concrete application in mind, 
just an abstract model like in image(s) above consisting of load, source
and the transmission line between them.

And if we take a look on your two examples **1)** the transmitter circuit
(as source) and output antenna (as load) and 
**2)** two IC's interacting via high speed signals, then clearly both systems
can be modeled as above by this abstract model.

Comment: Now my motivation was to extract a pure formal reason (not just a
"by means of experience"-reason) why for the first case we use maximal 
power transfer and in secound the minimal reflection.

About your first example with transmitter circuit & output antenna you said 
that we should use the maximize power
transfer option because that's finaly what we want there: to 
maximize power output (ie to provide maximal power to the antenna considered
as load).

Comment: But at this point I could object that if there occure some
reflected waves on the transmission line laying between the
transmitter circuit and the output antenna, these reduce the
power transfered to the antenna as load as well. So the crucial question
at this point is why at this point it's is more reasonable to do
maximize power transfer instead of minimal reflection?
What's the formal reason to choose in this case the maximize
power transfer option instead of minimize reflection of waves?

Comment: My attempt:
Considering the transmitter & output antenna system
one can maybe argue that in **this** concrete system the transmission line is relatively
short with respect the used wavelength, such that the effect of the transmission 
line causing finally the reflected waves is very small und therefore 
can be just ignored/neglected in our considerations. So the maximization
of power transfer is here more important.

Comment: On the other hand in case of your second example with high speed signals between two ICs
one can argue that in this system the effect due to reflected signal waves 
is **not** negligible any more for example if the transmission line is spreaded
over a long distance, and so the negative effect do to reflected waves is more
dramatic (and is more important to be managed), then a not optimal power
transfer. So we conclude that it's more important here to minimize the reflection
waves that to maximize the power transfer.

Comment: Firstly, are my reasoning correct or do then run in wrong direction. 
Secoundly, if what I said before is not wrong, can it be used 
to extract abstract criteria based on formal parameters (like eg length
of transmission lines) when for a given system it is more important to 
perform the maximization of power transfer and when to minimize the signal
wave reflection?

Comment: impedance mismatch is not caused just by transmission line, it also depends on source and load impedances. As for your other comments, I don't have a better answer - it depends on your application and its requirements. For digital high speed signals, reflections may cause false detection of levels that will corrupt the data, this is why it is important to minimize reflections. For wireless communication you don't have this issue and you are mainly concerned with power (which gives you better SNR and larger transmission distance)

Comment: So one can say in summary that, depending on the specific application
it's a "weighing up" business,  so there is no "universal" guideline available; 
one should ask oneself what is the "lesser evil" in a concrete
situation?
Some losses of transfered energy or the presence
of reflected waves on the line? Right?

Comment: This is how I consider such problems - while doing design, it is always a game of trade-offs