# Guideline for Impedance Matching (simplified cases)

Tags: rf, transmission-line, impedance-matching

Dealing with [impedance matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching) of RF networks one facing
two common techniques:
(a) maximize power transfer
(b) minimize reflexion of signal waves

In [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595368/maximum-power-transfer-and-minimization-of-signal-reflection-when-should-what-b/595429?noredirect=1#comment1564855_595429) I have tried to develop some kind of 'intuition' when
I should try to maximize the power transfer in my network and when
to minimize the reflexion of signal waves. I think that in such full generality it was a combat with wind mills, so for general networks there is
no 'general guide' available, but nevertheless I would like to
know if there some 'elementary guide rules' appliable in case of
simplified networks. Namely I would like to discuss these three
rather elementary cases:

[image]

My question is simply can it for these 3 simple, but didactically interesting
cases definitely said if we should apply (a) or (b) in 'guideline manner'? My ideas:

CASE 1: Here is assumed that there is no transmission line between source
and load. Or there is a transmission line between them, but is at least assumed that it's
length is short compared to the frequences the networks works with.

my guess: If we impose these assumtion, can it be stated as a 'rule' that
in this case one should always apply (a), the maximize power transfer
archieved by \$Z_S= Z^*_L\$

CASE 2: Here we assume that the source is connected to the transmission line
with big length and we don't know what sits behind the transmission line.

Guess: Can for such situations be said that here one should *always*  apply
(b), the minimization of the signal waves reflexion, that is
\$Z_S= Z_T\$

CASE 3: Assume now that the load is connected to the transmission line and
we don't know from whom the signal comes, that is we don't know the
source. That means the load sees only the transmission line.

Guess: Does this case obeys the same rule like chase 2, that means
here we should always apply (b) for the transmission line and load?

Firstly, are my ideas correct? In other works can it be said
that it should be regarded as  guideline to apply for cases 1,2,3
(a), (b), (b) and nothing else?

If that's true, can we extract from this a more general principle dealing
with multi-staged networks? Say, we have a network consisting of
\$k\$ consecutive parts \$P_1=S, P_2,..., P_k=L\$ and we want to know how to match it.
As I remarked, in general that's a difficult question. But can we
nevertheless state following two principles, which we can consider
as rough 'guidelines'?

[image]

1. the matching should be done successively between direct neighbours.
   Firstly we match \$P_1\$ to \$P_2\$, then \$P_2\$ to \$P_3\$, and so on. So
   we can divide the matching problem to \$k-1\$ 'small' matching problems between
   \$P_i\$ and \$P_{i+1}\$
2. we want to match \$P_i\$ and \$P_{i+1}\$. Can we consider the following
   suggestion as a general guideline?

> "If \$P_i\$ or \$P_{i+1}\$ is a transmission line, then we always should match
> \$P_i\$ and \$P_{i+1}\$ by (b): minimization of reflexion, that is our aim is \$Z_i= Z_{i+1}\$?"

and if neither \$P_i\$, nor \$P_{i+1}\$ is a transmission line, then our task is to
get (a): \$Z_i= Z^*_{i+1}\$?
Do my considerations make sense? Is there something wrong?

Comment: You are limiting yourself the scenarios that are naive. For instance, you would never ever match a speaker impedance with the output impedance of an amplifier. To do so is missing the point hence, many many times your load is much higher impedance compared with the source impedance and, is done so by choice.

Comment: Most RF circuitry is based on 50 ohm source and load impedances.

Comment: @Andy: okay, my motivation has pure didactic nature. 
maybe from practical point of view this approach 
misses in fact the point, I still have a terrible 
intuition in this area. I hoped just to understand this field 
better with this divide and conquer approach. But 
could you say to me, are my ideas on cases 1-3 
at least pure theoretically fine? or is there something that I'm doing conceptually wrong? For example, I'm not sure it I understand how to see when I should try to reach the procedure (a) and when (b). Is there a kind of rough guideline known?

Comment: I find it hard to answer questions that assert wrong things. Now that's my problem in that I feel disinclined to spend time unwrapping incorrect formed ideas. Sorry.

Comment: @Andy: would you like to point out which of my assertions
is wrong? Is there something wrong with cases 1,2,3 
I going to discuss in general? Did I make somewhere a false claim in my attepts to solve them? 

If you if you are not averse, I would like to discuss 
 with you the example with the speaker and 
amplifier you brought in the conversion. hopefully
that will convey your concern to me better.

Comment: first of all, how do you want to model it? 
Is it ok, if we try to model it as I suggested 
in the second picture, that is as the chain of subcomponents
\$ P_1 (=source) -.- P_2 -.- ... -.- P_k (=load)\$
where "\$-.- \$" symbols the double wire as in second pic?

next, it sounds resonable to consider want subcomponents
are involved and next how to match them, 
do you here argee with me?

Comment: our system consists of the a source from where the signal comes from, the amplifier, which does what an amplifier does, and a speaker as load, which receives the amplified signal, that's ok? my suggestion: take \$ P_1 (=source)\$ as initial source,
like a microphone in your example. next, what should be 
\$ P_2 \$? natural choice: the amplifier. And 
what should be \$ P_3 \$? the speaker as the load. 
at first glance this assignment looks reasonable. But:
here start my problems: clearly between 
\$ P_1 \$ and \$ P_2 \$ (and between \$ P_2 \$ and \$ P_2 \$)
there are transmission lines.

Comment: Should we here really try to match directly
\$ P_1 \$ and \$ P_2 \$ or should we add between then
an additional compoenent \$ P_{12} \$ which 
represents the transmission line and try 
to reduce the matching problem for \$ P_1 \$ and \$ P_2 \$
to two matching problems firstly between
\$ P_1 \$ and \$ P_{12} \$, secondly between
\$ P_{12} \$ and \$ P_2 \$?  Is this 
approach reasonable. If not, please point out
the wrong assertion? It's very important to me and
I would like really understand what you mean.

Comment: You're getting wrapped around the axle of impedance matching. Sometimes it's important, sometimes it's not. For Audio frequencies, it's generally not important Optimum power transfer isn't as important, as gain is much simpler to achieve. For RF circuitry , it's important, as gain is expensive and harder to achieve.

Comment: @rfdave: But as I said my principal motivation
is to study it as didactically valuable example to analyze 
when should be applied which technique.
Before one studies
a compex object, one should probably study 
it's pieces or reduce it's compexity. often a lot of phenomena
come to light in a complex system can be already
studied in simplified systems, that's how science 
works.

Comment: If you think that the example with
the speaker and amplifier not captures
any knowledge how to match impedance, 
then suggest another example say where you think 
impedance matching is important and where one can better
understand if one should maximize power transfer
or minimize reflection waves.

Comment: Impedance matching is a single tool in an engineers toolbox. Think of it like a hammer. There are times when you are building something that requires the use of a hammer, like when you're nailing something together. If you're using a screw, then a hammer is a wrong tool, and a screwdriver is the right tool.
The Canonical answer to any somewhat complicated engineering question is "It depends". You are aware of matching impedance's and a procedure to do it. . Whether you need to or not is going to depend on the specifics of problem in front of you.

Comment: @rfdave: From slightly different viewpoint your hammer & screwdriver 
metaphor illustrates quite good the motivation of
this question, since that's exactly what I want
to understand when I should apply the hammer
and when the screwdriver. when the maximization
of power transfer (\$Z_S= Z^*_L\$) and when 
minimization of reflection waves
(\$Z_S= Z_L\$). In trade you can simply say, if you use nail, 
work with hammer, if you use 
screw, well... my brain is tired right now

Comment: And that's exactly what I want to understand here. 
for example it appears that every time when there is 
transmission line long with resp wave lengths
involved, one might use the minimization of reflection waves.
but I nowhere found literature about this area which state
this as a rule, it just something what I assume that it 
might be true. similar story with maximization of
power transfer. can it be said when it is preferred over
the the minimization of reflection waves?

Comment: Wait, let's roll back this discussion. Why do you think there is a difference between maximizing power transfer and minimizing reflection waves? Power at an interface is either transmitted or reflected.

Comment: it's already in pure mathematical terms wrong: you cannot archieve conditions \$Z_S= Z^*_L\$ and \$Z_S= Z_L\$ simultaneously if the impedances have non zero reactance components. The two concept only coincide if the impedances are purely resistive

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of thumb for RF circuitry is that inputs and outputs are matched to 50 Ohms, so for Case 2 and Case 3 you would want to have the source and load presenting a 50 Ohm Output / Input impedance respectively.
For Multi-staged systems, which Case 1 is a degenerate example, it partially depends on the implementation.For PCB based systems, where you're going to want to be able to probe performance on the board, matching circuit blocks to 50Hms makes the evaluation/optimization easier.
If you're implementing the system in a RFIC, then you're free to not match the circuit blocks, and use Voltage/Current/Impedance as needed. Low output impedance/high input impedance is fine there.

Comment: thank you for your answer. these 50 Ohms you 
introduced, apparently fall from the sky. Does 
it have any physical background why we choose 50 Ohms and
not 10 or 100? or is it a convention? As well, this rule
only applies only to cases 2,3, therefore only if
one of the components we want to match is 
a transmission line?

Comment: As with many things in engineering, the origin story of the convention of 50 Ohms is somewhat unknown. For a coaxial cable, minimum losses are ~ 90 Ohms (Air filled lines) and maximum power handling is ~ 30 to 40 ohms, so 50 Ohms was chosen in WW2 as a compromise, and had developed into an industry standard.
As to you second question, many RF circuits (Not just transmission lines) are modeled as a  series of 2 port networks, and 50 Ohms is used as the standard impedance, used for Cables/connectors as well as test equipment.

Comment: okay, so can we endow this business with 50 Ohm with a model abstraction? suggestion: (Source)- (transmission line with std impedance 50 Ohm) - (Load) and then reduce the problem to two separate problems: 1. match source impedance to the impdance of transmission line (our 50 Ohm) and 2. match tranmission line to load. or does this again miss the point?

Comment: Yes, typically, you would match a source to 50 ohms, and a load to 50 ohms, and then you could use a 50 Ohm transmission line to connect the two.

Comment: but then, what is the difference between this 
approach you suggesting by 
introducing this 'virtual' transmission line with
\$Z_0=50 Ohm \$ and match separately 
the source and then the load with it (so you
have to archieve \$Z_S= Z_0\$ and \$Z_0= Z_L\$), 
or alternatively just to match the source with load
by maximum power transfer condition \$Z_S= Z^*_L\$?

Comment: Have you ever actually impedance matched a circuit? Using a "virtual" 50 ohm point allows you to use a vna to match a circuit to 50 ohms on both the input and output, giving you a characterized circuit block in a 50 ohm environment. You can the use that as a known block in your system.

Comment: Spend some time looking at the actual impedance values and VSWR. A 10 to 15 dB return loss is pretty good, so figure out what impedance variation would give you that return loss. Also look at the Smith Chart for a graphical approach.

Comment: here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/597640/impedance-matching-with-l-matching-network-cooking-recipe I explained at least theoretically how I understand the impedance matching procedure with L-matching networks. Essentially it seems (if I not misunderstand the stuff) that the whole magic behind it is that if one wants to match two components connected by a double line as above, one put's a matching network (the orange box in linked question) and determines the 'right' parameters to archive the match. There I sketched it only for L-matching network, but roughly the same

Comment: aproach - but with weirder math - should work for any matching network, like eg T-MN or multistaged-MN,... That's how I understand the impedance matching. Is there something wrong in my considerations?