# Impedance matching with L-matching network: cooking recipe

Tags: rf, impedance-matching, matching

I would like to try to elaborate in detail how I think one should perform in detail practically
impedance match between source and load via maximal power transfer using
a L-matching network and whould like to know if my approach is correct.

Suggestion: I would like to describe now how I understood it and I would
happy about any feedback on if I did it correct or wrong and how to repair it.

How I would do it:

1. We start with network consisting of source S with impedance \$Z_S\$ and
   load L with impedance \$Z_L\$. In general \$ Z_S \neq Z_L^*\$.

[image]

2. What we do next. We put the L-matching network (the 'orange box') between
   source and load.

[image]

Internally a single L-matching network is a combination of a capacitor and
a coil in one of the following possible configurations can be found eg
[here](https://www.smeter.net/feeding/l-network-terminating-impedance.php) or [there](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electronics/Microwave_and_RF_Design_III_-_Networks_(Steer)/06%3A_Chapter_6/6.4%3A_The_L_Matching_Network)

Assume, we take the first one:

[image]

3. The reactances \$j \cdot X_C\$ and \$j \cdot X_I\$ of the capacitor and coil are not
   known and if we want to archieve an perfect match, these should be
   adapted.
4. Next, the most crucial part for me is which conditions should the
   satisfied by the still unknown \$j \cdot X_C\$ and \$j \cdot X_I\$?

My guess is that to determine \$X_C\$ and \$X_I\$ following equations
should be satisfied:

(I) \$Z_S = Z_{in}^*\$
(II) \$Z_{out} = Z_L^*\$

where \$Z_{in} \$ and \$Z_{out} \$ are following impedances:

[image]

So formally we are done at that point: \$Z_{in} \$ and \$Z_{out} \$ contain
\$X_C \$ and \$X_I\$ as unknown variables and our task is to find
\$X_C\$ and \$X_I\$ solving equations (I) and (II).

Questions:

**A.** Is in principle the procedure I have written done above to match impedance via
L-matching network correctly explained?

**B.** If the answer to *A.* is positive, I'm not rather sure how
to to express \$Z_{out} \$ in terms of \$ Z_S, X_C, X_I\$.

\$Z_{in} \$ is rather simple:
[image]

\$j \cdot X_{I} \$ is in series to
parallel block of \$j \cdot X_{C} \$ and \$Z_{L} \$, which has impedance
\$ \frac{1}{\frac{1}{j \cdot X_C}+ \frac{1}{Z_{L}}} \$, therefore

$$ Z_{in}= j \cdot X_{I}+ \frac{1}{\frac{1}{j \cdot X_C}+ \frac{1}{Z_{L}}}    $$

by construction. What is \$Z_{out} \$ in terms of \$ Z_S, X_C, X_I\$?

**C.** Can we play verbatim the same game if we want to reach minimal signal reflection instead of maximal power transfer (for example if our load is a transmission line) with small correction that everywhere we required \$ Z_A = Z_B^*\$ we replace by the conditions \$ Z_A = Z_B \$ but esle the the steps 1-4 go throgh? Is does this procedure above only works for maximum power transfer?

---

**Addendum - respond to Andy's concern**:

In your calculations you
succeed in calculation of \$Z_{in} \$. As I said
\$Z_{in} \$ by definition equals the impedance
of the replacement circuit of:

[image]

and the missing impedance is \$Z_{out} \$ which
should arise as:

[image]

It's not clear how your calculations below can be used / adapted to calculate \$Z_{out} \$.

Comment: I would urge you to reconsider the procedure outlined in **Question A**...it is too complex. Start by setting aside reactive components of \$Z_S\$ and of \$Z_L\$. They become \$R_S, R_L\$. Prof. Ali M. Niknejad applies a nicely intuitive approach: http://rfic.eecs.berkeley.edu/142/pdf/module6.pdf

Comment: @glen_geek: but are there any conceptual errors in my reasonings in steps 1-4?

Comment: I can see that by including *reactive* component of \$Z_S\$ and reactive component of \$Z_L\$, you *may* make the goal of impedance match unachievable if they dominate the two purely reactive components of the **L-network**....be prepared to accept a sign-change of the components in the L-network. Or from a different point of view, there is a reactive value of \$Z_S\$ when combined with a reactive value of \$Z_L\$ that give a "matched" condition: no L-network is needed.

Comment: @glen_geek: 
you mean that the pure mathematical part may fail 
if we allow arbitrary \$ Z_S \$ and
\$ Z_L \$ as initial parameter and aim
as our goal to find capacitor & coil with
appropriate values \$ X_C \$ and \$ X_I \$
satisfying (I) \$Z_S = Z_{in}^*\$  
(II) \$Z_{out} = Z_L^*\$ stated in 4? Then 
is could happen that such 
\$ X_C \$ and \$ X_I \$ not exist?

Comment: There will always be component values of the L-network to achieve match. Be aware that their **sign** may switch, turning L's into C's (and C's into L's). I think you're approach is OK, but awkward. Also be aware that some solutions require component values that may be lossy, or require tight tolerance. That's especially true when ZS differs greatly from ZL.

Comment: The impedance of the impedance matching circuit must always be the conjugate of the impedance of the load in order for maximum power to be consumed by the load.

Comment: @glen_geek: assume from now we are working with pure resistive
components: \$ Z_S = R_S, Z_L=R_L  \$
do you see how to calculate \$ Z_{out} \$? 
it looks much harder than the 
calculation of \$ Z_{out} \$ which can be 
easly calculated using basic rules for
adding up impedances for parallel and serial 
components, see first picture below 
question **B.**. to calculate \$ Z_{out} \$
we deal with the part of circuit including
the signal generator Vs. do you know 
how to calculate \$ Z_{out} \$? my idea
was to find a replacing circuit, see
third picture below **B.**. could it work?

Comment: For \$Z_{out}\$, I would convert the series arm of \$V_S, Z_S, jX_l\$ into its Norton equivalent of conductance, susceptance. Then you have a simple parallel circuit.

Comment: @glen_geek: in my last comment there is a typo: I meant of course '... do you see how to calculate \$Z_{out} \$? it looks much harder than the calculation of \$Z_{in} \$ !!! which can be easly calculated using ...'

Comment: on your suggestion to use Norton equivalent circuit: it seems that then we obtain exactly what we want, namely the new circuit of the form as pictured in the third picture on the right below **B** but with small difference that in general the voltage of the signal general in the Norton equivalent is not the same as of the original circuit: \$(V_S)' \neq V_S\$, but it not matters, or does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An L-pad derivation can be found on my website [here](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20Lpad%20LP.html). You can use the web calculator provided and here's an example of matching 50 Ω to 300 Ω at 10 MHz: -

[image]

As you can see, the formulas are shown in the picture but, the derivation is shown further down: -

[image]

> *Is in principle the procedure I have written done above to match
> impedance via L-matching network correctly explained?*

It looks about right but, given my website derives it for you, you can double check this yourself.

- [High-pass L-pad matching](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20Lpad%20HP%20.html)
- [Low-pass Pi filter matching](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20PI%20LP.html)
- [High-pass T filter matching](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20T%20HP%20.html)

The Pi and T filter links also show you how to cascade to get really sharp cut-offs that can be quite appropriate for RF antenna circuits to avoid emissions that might be outside legal requirements.

---

**Addendum 1 - the output impedance is purely resistive and equal to 300 Ω at 10 MHz**

The simulation circuit uses a source at the position of \$Z_{OUT}\$ and a zero Ω resistor to measure the phase angle of the current taken from the source: -

[image]

The AC analysis: -

[image]

I don't think that there can be any doubt about the impedance looking into the output node being 300 Ω and purely resistive. Of course if you want to prove that then just spend a couple of hours hammering your way through the maths. I'm not going to do that of course (or am I?).

---

**Addendum 2 - series to parallel inductor-resistor calculator**: -

[image]

The derivation of the conversion is shown on the [same website](https://analog.intgckts.com/impedance-matching/series-to-parallel-conversion/): -

[image]

Do you really need any more convincing? I suppose you do: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Andy, that covers the case
where the impedances of source and load are
real: \$ Z_S = R_S, Z_L=R_L  \$
One aspect is not quite evident there. 
You give a formula for \$ Z_{in} \$, the 
value of \$ Z_{out} \$ is not involved in your 
considerations. seemingly because it is not
neccessary to determine \$ X_C \$ and \$ X_I \$. 
Do you nevertheless know
how it can be calculated?

Comment: I think you need to run with this yourself now. I've shown you the proofs for resistive impedance. Just modify my technique for complex impedance OR, recognize that you can cancel the reactive elements with the opposite value series reactances thus leaving you you with resistive values. This is how you'd match an antenna to a complex driver impedance.

Comment: what is a 'driver' as technical term in this context? is it used synonymously to 'source'?

Comment: as well there is problem why 
as I think it becomes rather more difficult 
to calculate \$ Z_{out} \$ than
\$ Z_{in} \$ and why your technique for 
calculations of 
cannot \$ Z_{in} \$ 
be straight forwardly adapted to calculate
\$ Z_{out} \$. take a look at the picture
I added below question **B.** to emphasize the problem I have now:

Comment: the calculation of
\$ Z_{in} \$ as you showed is a simple yoga
with parallel and serial impedances, the 
techniques to do it are well known.
we calculate at first the impedance of parallel
\$ jX_C \$ and \$ Z_S \$ and then 
add to it \$ jX_I \$ according to calculation
rule for impedances in series. it's easy. the calculation of \$ Z_{out} \$ includes
the signal generator as well. how should it be
treated in calculation of \$ Z_{out} \$?
should it be completely ignored?

Comment: Simply put, if Zin is purely resistive then that power is going somewhere and, that means that the power must be entering the only other resistive component in the circuit, namely Rout. A driver is English for a prime mover or source. Pretty standard language really.

Comment: I dont see how you can say that my formula don’t include Rout. I call it RL in my derivations. Do you see that know. I believe the picture in the answer to be fairly clear.

Comment: perhaps it becomes clearer what I mean
by \$ Z_{out} \$ considering the fourth picture here:
https://rahsoft.com/2021/04/13/understanding-the-need-of-matching-networks/

In our case since we are working with resistive
source and load we have \$ Z_{L}=R_L \$. 
but my point is that you can't simply
*call* or *define* \$ Z_{out} \$ *a priori* as \$ Z_{L}\$ 
(or in our case \$ R_{out} = R_{L}\$). That's
a nontrivial condition for 
the parameters \$ X_C \$ and \$ X_I \$ on which  \$ Z_{out} \$
a priori depends.

Comment: that's the same story as for \$ Z_{in} \$. the equation 
\$ Z_{out} = Z_S^*\$ is not a definition, it's a condition 
which should be satisfied by \$ Z_{out}\$ as a function depending
on \$ X_C \$ and \$ X_I \$, the formula which you derived on you website.

 
and my question is about \$ Z_{out} \$:
how this dependence of \$ Z_{out} \$ on
\$ X_C \$ and \$ X_I \$ is expressed as explicit formula?

Comment: I updated again the graphic below my question **B.** by a third picture to clarify what I mean. perhaps this makes my concern better understandable.

Comment: This isn't a progressive teaching forum where solutions are hammered out over many interactive comments; this is a Q and A site. I suggest you get hold of a simulator, plug-in some values implied by my formula and see for yourself that the input and output impedances are absolutely correct (which of course they are). As to "Q: how to deal with Vs?" - Vs is just shorted out in order to compute Zout/Rout. It's fairly trivial really. It's based on superposition.

Comment: So then, the impedance looking into your 2nd picture under "B" is \$\dfrac{1}{j\omega C}\$ in parallel with \$j\omega L + R_{SOURCE}\$.

Comment: Just for you @user7391733 I've simulated the 50 ohm input, 300 ohm output impedance scenario at 10 MHz - see addendum to my answer.

Comment: note that my penultimate comment contains
some copy & paste typos: I wanted to say there:
that's the same story as for \$Z_{in}\$: the equation 
\$Z_{in}= Z_{S}^*\$ is not (!!!) a definition, 
it's a condition 
which should be satisfied by \$Z_{in}\$ as a function 
depending on \$X_{C}\$ and \$X_{I}\$, the formula which you
derived on you website. and my question is about 
\$Z_{out}\$: how this dependence of \$Z_{out}\$ on 
\$X_{C}\$ and 
\$X_{I}\$ is expressed as explicit formula?

Comment: and yes as I already said I know how 
to calculate \$Z_{in}\$. 
My concern relates to \$Z_{out}\$, see also
https://rahsoft.com/2021/04/13/understanding-the-need-of-matching-networks/
what I mean by \$Z_{out}\$. and ok, if you don't 
like mathematical explanations, could you 
at least explain it more conceptionally 
how to obtain this \$Z_{out}\$ from the impedances of
the source and components
of the L-matching network. can it be obtained
by a sequence of transformations replacing it by 
an Theverin equivalent circuit? the 
main cause of the problem is surely the 
capacitor...

Comment: I've clearly demonstrated that Zo is resistive. I've also explained that if Zin is resistive and equal to Zsource (which it is) then power must be taken from the source at the correct ratio and, the only component that can dissipate this is the resistive load on the output. So, are you genuinely truly having problems accepting that despite what I say? Does your original question totally boil down to proving the output resistance value? Think carefully here.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort to try to help 
me to solve the problems but yes the 
determination of \$Z_{out} \$ as stated in my 
partial question **B.** is one of the most important
parts I originally asked for.

in addendum above in my question I explained what 
you have explained and what is
in my opinion missing.

Comment: moreover in your last comment where you wrote that if we 
succed to obtain Zin = Zsource, then
the only component that can dissipate this is the 
resistive load on the output, do you refer 
to the implication that the attempt to try
in addition to obtain Zout= Zload is a redundant 
step?

Comment: Well I did finally give you a proof above and yes, it is a redundant step. If we are done here you should accept my answer formally.

Comment: why do you think that it's possible for the calculations to short source \$ V_S \$ in your simulation circuit from Addendum 1? and why you introduce the voltage \$ V_1 \$ on the load side? wouldn't it not have been easier to align the modelings of  \$ Z_{out} \$ with those suggested in https://rahsoft.com/2021/04/13/understanding-the-need-of-matching-networks/ and based on this, carry out the calculations?

Comment: @user7391733 (1) The input impedance of a port is unrelated to any voltage source that is present and connected to another port. (2) So, the connected voltage source \$V_S\$ could be 1 MHz @ 10 volts or (for example), 10 mV @ 1 Hz or DC of any value. (3) This gives us the freedom to make the voltage source whatever value and frequency we wish in order to find the impedance of another port. (4) For convenience, I choose 0 volts for \$V_S\$.

Comment: @user7391733 (1) In the simulation, the measurement of the impedance presented to V1 (by components C1, L1 and R1) it makes use of R2 (as a convenient placeholder) to help analysis. (2) So, if you look at the graphical AC analysis result, I plot the voltage Vx divided by the current through R2 in the top graph (v(Vx)/i(R2). (3) Because that top graph is a magnitude bode plot it ignores phase relationship and works with amplitude magnitude (as with any bode plot response). (4) The lower part is the phase response and, it works with the phase angle result of i(R2).

Comment: @user7391733 `wouldn't it not have been easier to align the modelings of Zout with those suggested in rahsoft.com` - does that matter now? I showed 3 different ways to solve it and rahsoft shows one way. So now, in total you have four methods and, there's probably more to find. Anyway, in the first line of rahsoft it says this: `Maximum power delivery is the main objective while designing a circuit in RF systems` - I considered that was a rather weak stance to take and, it put me off analysing their page in detail - it's the reduction of standing waves that is most important IMHO.

Comment: I will also add that rahsoft says this: `The matching network is always designed using the reactive elements like inductance, and capacitance (L and C). The matching network never includes resistance, as it absorbs the average power` - that is rather naïve. Plenty of times we use a taper pad (attenuating impedance matching network) so, I take issue with the word `always` used in the above sentence. Neither do I like the way they said that capacitive reactance is `1/jcw`. The terms "j" and "w" are so closely linked that it is very naïve not to refer to capacitive reactance as "1/jwC".